# imread_collection There is no item

Tags: python, zip, scikit-image

I am trying to read several images from archive with [skimage.io.imread_collection](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread_collection), but for some reason it throws an error:

> "There is no item named '00071198d059ba7f5914a526d124d28e6d010c92466da21d4a04cd5413362552/masks/*.png' in the archive".

I checked several times, such directory exists in archive and with *.png I just specify that I want to have all images in my collection, and `imread_collection` works well, when I am trying to download images not from archive, but from extracted folder.

```
#specify folder name
each_img_idx = '00071198d059ba7f5914a526d124d28e6d010c92466da21d4a04cd5413362552'

with zipfile.ZipFile('stage1_train.zip') as archive:
    mask_ = skimage.io.imread_collection(archive.open(str(each_img_idx) + '/masks/*.png')).concatenate()
```

May some one explain me, what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Not all scikit-image plugins support reading from bytes, so I recommend using `imageio`.  You'll also have to tell ImageCollection how to access the images inside the archive, which is done using a customized `load_func`:

```
from skimage import io
import imageio

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('foo.zip')
images = [f.filename for f in zf.filelist]

def zip_imread(fn):
    return imageio.imread(archive.read(fn))

ic = io.ImageCollection(images, load_func=zip_imread)
```

ImageCollection has some benefits like not loading all images into memory at the same time.  But if you simply want a long list of NumPy arrays, you can do:

```
collection = [imageio.imread(zf.read(f)) for f in zf.filelist]
```